# Maven Comile Will Stuck At search path for class files

Tags: maven, java-11

I upgrade jdk8 to jdk11, and use maven to compile project, but it stuck at [search path for class files: ...], why? And I found if I remove dependency [taobao-sdk-java-auto], it will package successfully, so this dependency is not compatible with jdk11? It works in jdk8. And MWE is in demo repo at github: https://github.com/bqdong/mwe-jdk11, can anyone know how to solve it? Thansks. I use maven 3.6.3.

I follow maven debug mode, but cannot find the problem. Reproduce steps are describe at github repo README file.

Comment: Can you please explain more in detail what you mean by: `but it stuck at`... The compatibilty of a jar files is not a reason for stucking ... or alike... apart from that why do you use old Maven version?

Comment: @khmarbaise I don't know why it stuck at that step in jdk11. It works in jdk8. I want to package, but after executing `mvn clean package`, it stop at that step, so I cannot get result. The github link is a minimal work example.  Reproduce steps in README file. I just want to know why it doesn't work at jdk11.

Comment: It's working without any issue ... using Maven 3.9.3 JDK17 no issue... ? Even working with Maven 3.6.3...Can you show a log output of the stucking build...

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks, I also try use JDK 17, it works. But use JDK11, it stuck. Build log I  commit to github repo, and generation command is  `mvn -X clean package`.  According to log, it stuck at [search path for class files]. Then it won't have any progress. That's a strange question.

Comment: I would suggest to use a more recent version of JDK11 ... and try that..

Comment: It work in Oracle JDK 11 download from https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk11-archive-downloads.html, but not work in OpenJDK 11 download from https://jdk.java.net/archive/